# Facebook user_friends permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-permissions

On my app, i have a feature that uses the user's facebook "user_friends" permission.
It used to work before they upgraded to API V.2.0, but now it does not:
When I created the app on FB and used test users (in development mode) my feature that includes this permission worked.
But, when i turned on the app (to be live) - it does not work.
So - it works on Test users but not on Live users.
How is that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Answer (score 5):

This is because `/me/friends` will only return those friends which also have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends/#readperms

> - This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.
> - If a friend of the person declines the user_friends permission, that friend will not show up in the friend list for this person.